# Clicking beside dialog hides the dialog

Tags: android, dialog

At start of my Android app I show a dialog in the middle of the screen ( fills 30% of the screen) indicating that the app is loading ( takes 1 minute ). 
When I click outside of the dialog ( 70%) the dialog disappears and I have a black screen.

How can I prevent this ?

At start I set :

```
tbl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
```

and then during loading I do :

```
HprogressDialog = new HistoryProgressDialog(this);
HprogressDialog.show();

new Thread() {

        public void run() {
...
...
```

any hints ?

( This problem I did not have in the past. So I guess it could be of upgrading to a higher API-Level ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this..

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves it. What would I do without this forum and helpful community
I accepted for Piyush Gupta, because he was 1 minute faster. Thanks for Kalyan Pvs too.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line before show `dialog`..

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves it. What would I do without this forum and helpful community
I accepted for Piyush Gupta, because he was 1 minute faster. Thanks for Kalyan Pvs too.

Comment: Piyush Gupta had 58min and you 59min. Also the answers are sorted by incoming if not rated and Piyush Gupta was on top. Sorry . Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user1344545 place the cursor on "answered 3 hours ago" text for both answers you will see timings with seconds also..until accept they will never in sorted order..they are random order if same votes cast for answers..

Comment: You are right. But I really checked the times when it was displayed as minutes. I will check that with future answers. I hope you will understand that I can't change status now. I upgraded your answer too. So you got silver insteed :-)